# Algorithms with sinusoidal complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I wonder if there is an algorithm which asymptotic complexity depends on the size of a problem in unusual way, i.e. not as a superposition of power/exponent/logarithm? For example, something like Θ(n ^ (2 + sin n))?

Comment: You can do basically whatever you want if you don't care if the algorithm is a natural algorithm for solving a natural problem (though your exact question doesn't make sense since you can't take the log of a negative number, which `sin n` will sometimes be).

Comment: @JohnColeman technically you could - the result will be a family of complex numbers; but defining a "complexity" will be impossible because there are infinitely many members and their magnitudes are unbounded

Comment: The purpose of asymptotic complexity is to study how, for some algorithm, the number of steps taken increases when the size of the input increases. A sinusoidal complexity would mean that the number of steps oscillates around some value, but that value would be constant. You may increase the input size thoudsandfold, the number of steps would remain roughly the same. In other words, the complexity in this case would be constant.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, if `f(n)` is a nonnegative function with the property that for large `n`, `f(n)` can be computed in less than `f(n)` steps, then the algorithm that first computes `f(n)` and then adds 1 to itself `floor(f(n))` times will have complexity `O(f(n))`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. You might want to try [math.se]

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you for pointing out the incorrectness of provided example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ ( though a trivial answer would be where you want to sort the values of a sinusoidal time series which are greater than the last recorded value )

Comment: As an example of a natural problem whose best algorithm would have an unusual complexity function: given the Cayley table of a group (in the sense of abstract algebra), determine if the group is a simple group. This can range from trivial to quite hard. It is trivial if a group has a prime number, p,  of elements (hence the size of the Cayley table would be n = p^2), but the general problem is somewhat hard. More generally, any problem in discrete mathematics where the complexity of the problem rests on the prime decomposition of the problem size will have a strange profile.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you! I know about discrete maths algorithms and technically your answer is absolutely right. Now I realize I should've polished my question to make it more strictly formal :) My question is indeed more about algorithms with complexity that can be expressed in terms of functions that are not trivial (like log/exp/pow), but that are also standard algebraic (not like Euler function, smallest prime divisor etc). And is there a possibility that there exist some natural problems that can require such strange number of operations if effectively solved?

Answer (score 0):

In general - usually you want to know "the worst possible case" for given input size of "n" and then you can compare it to another algorithms and their "worst possible case" to give you insight about what you should use.

So for the most straightforward answer the `O(n ^ (2 + sin n))` can be simply computer as - what is biggest value of sinus - it is `1` which leads us to `O(n ^ (2 + 1)) = O(n^3)`, therefore you can say that `n ^ (2 + sin n) = O(n^3)`.

---

However the real life is more complex than this. For example - quicksort actually has `O(n^2)`, but in average case it has `O(n*log n)`. The average case is quite hard to compute (you have to count all the permutations)

In your case - you are oscilating between `O(n)` and `O(n^3)`, so if I can use your algorithm and also was able to have another one with `O(n^2)`, I would choose the original one when `sin n < 0` and in other cases the `O(n^2)` one

Comment: Thank you. Actually I meant Theta-notation, not O-notation :-) And I'm asking more about the problem which, as you said, require one to oscillate between n and n^3 if effectively solved. Is there some natural cases (e.g., in physics) which can require such oscillating number of operations? Of course I am not sure there is any, but if there is, it would be very interesting!

Comment: Well I think Theta is basically unusable for this as ```n^1.65 != n^1.66``` in complexity theory, so you basically need almost same function to be equal.